# Аргументы функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

Программа рассчитывает калорийность
При клике на чекбоксы срабатывает функция и пишет общую каллорийность и цену.
Я захотел реализовать плавное изменение калорийности и цены без использования `jQuery`
Я не понимаю, как исправить ошибки js 
Я написал функцию `esc`, у которой есть в коде `document.getElementById(num)`, только дело в том, что `num` является аргументом функции, а `document.getElementById()` принимает только строку.

 Я пытался сделать строку из аргумента `num`, но всё равно ничего не получилось.
Возможно ошибка даже в чём-то другом. 
Я решил написать сам эту программу, но столкнулся с трудностями, буду рад, если мне поможете :)

Ссылка на codeopen: 
https://codepen.io/mihail-kamahin/pen/MMqBBo

```
    <h1>Бургер меню</h1>
    <p><input type="checkbox" checked disabled data-cost="10" data-kkal="75" class="menu">Булочка</p>
    <hr>
    <h2>Наполнение</h2>
    <p><input type="checkbox" checked data-cost="20" data-kkal="200" class="menu">Котлета</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="12" data-kkal="100" class="menu">Сыр</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="8" data-kkal="50" class="menu">Салат</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="2" data-kkal="20" class="menu">Огурец</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="4" data-kkal="67" class="menu">Помидор</p>
    <hr>
    <h2>Соусы</h2>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Томатный кетчуп</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Горчица</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Майонез</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Сычуанский соус</p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Итого:</h3>
    <p>
        Каллорийность: <span id="kkal"></span> 
        Цена: <span id="cost"></span>
    </p>
```

```
function getResult() {
    var cost = 0;
    var kkal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        if (menu[i].checked) {
            cost += parseFloat(menu[i].getAttribute('data-cost'));
            kkal += parseFloat(menu[i].getAttribute('data-kkal'));
        }
    }
    esc('cost', cost);
    esc('kkal', kkal);

    function esc(num, costAndKkal) {
        var x1 = 1;
        var x01 = 0.1;
        if (x1 > 0) {
            document.getElementById(num).style.opacity = x1;
            x1 = x1 - 0.1;
            setTimeout(esc, 100);
        } else {
            document.getElementById(num).innerHTML = costAndKkal;
            document.getElementById(num).style.opacity = x01;
            x01 = x01 + 0.1;
            setTimeout(esc, 100);
        }
    }
}

var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    menu[i].onclick = getResult;
}

getResult();
```

Comment: У вас "num" = 30, каким образом вы на число вешаете getElementById?

Comment: Ой, точно, попробую исправить)

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, вашу задумку с opacity. Не могу врубиться :) Чего вы ждёте от этого

Comment: У вас немало ошибок :)

Comment: Я добавил ответ, как я реализовал это, и там видно, что я хотел сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть некоторые косяки, типа если быстро кликать, то дёргается, так как я не подумал о таком баге, но у меня получилось самому реализовать такую штуку:

```js
function getResult() {
  var cost = 0;
  var kkal = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    if (menu[i].checked) {
      cost += parseFloat(menu[i].getAttribute('data-cost'));
      kkal += parseFloat(menu[i].getAttribute('data-kkal'));
    }
  }
  esc('cost', cost);
  esc('kkal', kkal);

  function esc(num, costAndKkal) {
    let opac = 1;
    if (opac != 0) {
      var timerId = setInterval(function() {
        opac = (opac * 10 - 0.1 * 10) / 10;
        document.getElementById(num).style.opacity = opac;
        if (opac == 0) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
          let timerId1 = setInterval(function() {
            opac = (opac * 10 + 0.1 * 10) / 10;
            document.getElementById(num).style.opacity = opac;
            document.getElementById(num).innerHTML = costAndKkal;
            if (opac == 1) {
              clearInterval(timerId1);
            }
          }, 15);
        }
      }, 15);
    }
  }
}

var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  menu[i].onclick = getResult;
}

getResult();
```

```html
<h1>Бургер меню</h1>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked disabled data-cost="10" data-kkal="75" class="menu">Булочка</p>
<hr>
<h2>Наполнение</h2>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked data-cost="20" data-kkal="200" class="menu">Котлета</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="12" data-kkal="100" class="menu">Сыр</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="8" data-kkal="50" class="menu">Салат</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="2" data-kkal="20" class="menu">Огурец</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="4" data-kkal="67" class="menu">Помидор</p>
<hr>
<h2>Соусы</h2>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Томатный кетчуп</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Горчица</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Майонез</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Сычуанский соус</p>
<hr>
<h3>Итого:</h3>
<p>
  Каллорийность: <span id="kkal"></span> Цена: <span id="cost"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Советую использовать делегирование вместо того, чтобы вешать обработчик на каждый элемент. Ну а так похвально, плюсик :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var opac = 0,
  cost = 30,
  kkal = 275;

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var target = event.target;

  if (!target.classList.contains('menu')) return;

  if (target.checked) {
    cost += parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-cost'));
    kkal += parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-kkal'));
  } else {
    cost -= parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-cost'));
    kkal -= parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-kkal'));
  }

  document.getElementById('kkal').innerHTML = kkal;
  document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = cost;

  var run = setInterval(() => {
    opac += 0.1
    document.querySelector('.end').style.opacity = opac;

    if (opac >= 1) {
      clearInterval(run);
    }
  }, 100)
})
```

```css
.end {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Бургер меню</h1>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked disabled data-cost="10" data-kkal="75" class="menu">Булочка</p>
<hr>
<h2>Наполнение</h2>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked data-cost="20" data-kkal="200" class="menu">Котлета</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="12" data-kkal="100" class="menu">Сыр</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="8" data-kkal="50" class="menu">Салат</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="2" data-kkal="20" class="menu">Огурец</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="4" data-kkal="67" class="menu">Помидор</p>
<hr>
<h2>Соусы</h2>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Томатный кетчуп</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Горчица</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Майонез</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" data-cost="5" data-kkal="10" class="menu">Сычуанский соус</p>
<hr>
<h3>Итого:</h3>
<p class='end'>
  Калорийность: <span id="kkal"></span> Цена: <span id="cost"></span>
</p>
```

Немного переделал ваш код